# Is it safe to pass as argument a member of an object which is moving

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct A {
    int n { 42 };
    std::string s { "ciao" };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::map<std::string, A> m;
    std::cout << "a.s: " << a.s << std::endl; // print: "a.s: ciao"
    m.emplace(a.s, std::move(a)); // a.s is a member of a, moved in the same line
    std::cout << "in map: " << m.count("ciao") << std::endl; // print: "in map: 1"
    std::cout << "a.s: " << a.s << std::endl; // print: "a.s: " (as expected, it has been moved)
}
```

Is it safe to pass as an argument a member of a "moving" object? In this case, emplace seems to work: the map has the expected key.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In this case, no `A` object is created in the call, since `std::map::emplace` takes universal references. If the second argument was taken by value, then indeed evaluation order would matter.

Comment: @DDrmmr After some reading of references/specs/Wintermutes answer, you're correct. This should be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. I think it's safe, for convoluted reasons. (For the record, **I also consider it very bad style** -- an explicit copy costs you nothing here, since it will be moved into the map.)

First of all, the actual function call is not a problem. `std::move` only casts `a` to an rvalue reference, and rvalue references are just references; a is not immediately moved. `emplace_back` forwards its parameters to a constructor of `std::pair<std::string, A>`, and this is where things get interesting.

So, which constructor of `std::pair` is used? It has rather many, but two are relevant:

```
pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);
template<class U, class V> pair(U&& x, U&&y);
```

(See 20.3.2 in the standard), where `T1` and `T2` are the template arguments of `std::pair`. As per 13.3, we end up in the latter with `U == const T1&` and `V == T2`, which makes intuitive sense (otherwise moving into a `std::pair` would be effectively impossible). This leaves us with a constructor of the form

```
pair(const T1& x, T2 &&y) : first(std::forward(x)), second(std::forward(y)) { }
```

as per 20.3.2 (6-8).

So, is this safe? Helpfully, `std::pair` is defined in some detail, including memory layout. In particular, it states that

```
T1 first;
T2 second;
```

come in this order, so `first` will be initialized before `second`. This means that in your particular case, the string will be copied before it is moved away, and you're safe.

However, if you were doing it the other way around:

```
m.emplace(std::move(A.s), A); // huh?
```

...then you'd get funny effects.

Comment: Where in the standard is it specified how `std::map::emplace` must be implemented? I think you are jumping to conclusions here.

Comment: 23.2.4, in table 102 (for all associative containers).

Comment: Are you sure, the compiler has to assume, that an rvalue and an lvalue reference can reference the same object? Otherwise, i believe, it would be allowed to reorder the initialization order in this case.

Comment: Er...that didn't cross my mind, to be honest. I mean, every time you call `std::move` you have an rvalue reference to an object on which lvalue references may exist -- not every rvalue is an xvalue. As far as I'm aware, there's nothing in the standard that says the compiler can assume an lvalue and an rvalue reference don't reference the same object, and the condition can arise quite naturally. I don't think that kind of optimization would be conforming.

Comment: This is the right answer, this is a particular case of defined behavior but I second the advice: *don't do it at home*

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you call `m.emplace(a.s, std::move(a));` is that you are passing an l-value reference to `a.s` and an r-value reference to `a` to the emplace function. Whether this is safe depends on the implementation of that function. If it first rips the guts out of the second argument and then tries to use the first argument, you'll likely have a problem. If it first uses the first argument and then rips the guts out of the second argument, no problem. Since this is a standard library function, you cannot rely on the implementation, so we cannot conclude that the code is safe.

To make it safe, you can make sure that a copy of the string is made before the contents of the string are moved out of `a`.

```
m.emplace(std::string(a.s), std::move(a));
```

Now you are passing an r-value reference to a temporary copy of `a.s` and an r-value reference to `a` to the emplace function. So, it's safe in this case, because `std::map::emplace` takes a set of universal references. If you would do the same with a function that takes it second argument by value, it's unsafe, because the move constructor could be called before the copy of `a.s` is made (since evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified). Knowing that, this code is probably too smart to be maintained.

So, the clearest code is something like:

```
auto key = a.s;
m.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(a));
```

Comment: Are you sure `m.emplace(std::string(a.s), std::move(a));` is safe? Isn't the order of evaluation undefined?

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato Evaluation order is unspecified (not undefined), but does not affect the result _in this particular case_. I've updated my answer to explain that better.

Comment: You say "you can make sure that a copy of the string is made before the contents of the string are moved out of a", but if the order is unspecified, how are you sure that string is copied before it is moved?

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato Because the copy has to be made before the function is called.

Comment: yeah, right, because std::move actually do nothing and emplace takes argument by universal reference, not by value